# Why are IE6 and IE7 not completely showing this div?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm having problems in IE6 and 7 with a div that doesn't complete the bottom padding that is attributed to it, so doesn't appear to finish the div down to the white content area like required.

Here's the coded homepage with the problem.

http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/Softwear/

The div house's this content:
Services : Design, Xhtml, Css, Flash Client : Newsletter Entrepeneur

I've tried display it as all sorts, clearing the div, and so on. I can't make heads or tails of it. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Any answers are greatly appreciated =S

Comment: Note: it's "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

Comment: Is it only the bottom padding of the #quickinfo div that is failing to render?

Comment: Software is spelled s-o-f-t-w-a-r-e.

Comment: Spelling doesn't matter at the moment, and I know of the softwear spelling mistake, but I didn't design or name it. I'm coding it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one of the [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) bugs. The background doesn't properly continue to the bottom when the element is displayed `inline`. Here's a [cite](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#inline) of the aforelinked site:

> For inline elements (either inline by
>   default like `span`, or having `display:
>   inline`)
>
> - `width` and `height` trigger
>     hasLayout in IE 5.x and IE 6 or newer
>     in quirks mode only. As of IE6, when
>     the browser is in
>     “standards-compliance mode” inline
>     elements will ignore the `width` and
>     `height` properties, and setting the
>     `width` and `height` properties will
>     not cause the element to have layout.
> - `zoom` always triggers hasLayout, but it's not supported in IE5.0.

As the [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) of your page is **strict** mode (standards compliance), your only resort is to give the element in question (the `#quickinfo`) a `zoom` style, apart from the obvious fix to display it as a `block` element (which is default for a `<div>` element).

```
#quickinfo {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "overflow:auto;zoom:1;" to the CSS. That seems to fix most of these IE layout bugs.